# How to create .jl file in IJulia

Tags: julia

I am very new to julia. I have just installed ipython and Ijulia. But every time I saved my file from ipython notebook, the format of the saved file is always .ipynb. I don't know if I can saved my file as .jl file. Or could anyone tell me how to create .jl file through ipython notebook. I have googled but seems like no one talks about it.

Comment: I am not sure about IJulia but in IPython you can save a notebook in code format (.py) - the option should be somwhere in file drop-down menu. `nbconvert` may also help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ipynb` is the JSON-based [Jupyter notebook format](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/nbformat.html), with conventions for storing code cells and associated metadata and data (such as inline images). Jupyter is designed as a fully-integrated interactive environment, not "just" a text editor, and as such the file format requires extra information. To create a `.jl` file, use a text editor or an ide such as [Juno](http://junolab.org/).